# Adjust references and captions

Tags: spacing

Please could you help me: I have a problem with my paper. In the reference section, the word "andothers" appear instead of "et al" how to fix it, please. And I need to add a space before figure and table caption ex: Fig.  a instead of Fig.a
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal, yet complete, code that we can test?

Comment: In particular, assuming you use BibTeX to create the bibliography, do please tell us which bibliography style and which citation managent package (if any) you employ.

Comment: I fixed the problem for the caption but the reference problem is still. I used the following code: \usepackage[sorting = none, backend = bibtex, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}